# Application of (Solomonoff) Algorithmic Probability formula?

Tags: probability-theory, induction, computer-science, information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

Ray Solomonoff gives the [Algorithmic Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_probability) formula as,

$$
P_M(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-|s_{i}(x)|}              \tag{1}
$$

​​​If I understand the formula correctly, $M$ is a Turing machine that outputs strings of symbols $x(n)$ with length $n$. Furthermore, $s$ (with length $n$) is a description of $x(n)$ in such a way that the symbols that are output by $M(n)$ would be the same as $x(n)$.

Thus, when computing Eq. (1), is $P_M$ the probability of observing (finite) string $x$ originating from Turing machine $M$ given observed strings $s_i$? Am I on the right track?

Does this mean that the Algorithmic Probability formula, given in Eq. (1), can be used to forecast any data (e.g. weather, population growth etc.)? If so, a simple mathematical example of it being used would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ indicate a prefix-free Universal Turing Machine, which can output strings using symbols in set $A$.
Let $M(s)$ indicate the output of this machine on input program $s \in \{0,1\}^*$. Then, the algorithmic probability of a finite string $x \in A^*$ (also sometimes known as the universal prior probability of $x$) is given by
\begin{align}
P_M(x) = \sum_{s: M(s) = x} 2^{-|s|} \,,
\end{align}
where $|s|$ indicates the length of program $s$ in bits.

$P_M(x)$ is the probability that machine $M$ would produce $x$ and halt ---if it were fed with random inputs (e.g., as generated by randomly flipping a coin for each input bit).  This probability is a special kind of "prior distribution", which assigns larger probabilities to $x$ that can be generated by short programs.  In fact, $P_M(x) = 2^{-K(x)}$, where $K(x)$ is the (prefix) Kolmogorov complexity of $x$ and equality holds up to a multiplicative constant (which doesn't depend on $x$).

Solomonoff induction is a way of using the distribution $P_M$ to make predictions, in a way which provides some special mathematical properties. Imagine that you observed some binary string $x = \langle x_1, x_2, \dots , x_{n-1}\rangle$ and you wish to predict whether the next bit will be $x_n = 0$ or $x_n = 1$.  Solomonoff induction suggests choosing the continuation that will make the entire sequence from $x_1$ to $x_n$ have highest algorithmic probability:
\begin{align}
x_n = \operatorname{argmax}_{x_n' \in \{0,1\}} P_M(\langle x_1, x_2, \dots , x_{n-1}, x_n' \rangle)
\end{align} 
More generally, one can make predictions by applying Bayes rule to the prior distribution $P_M$ (usually while also normalizing it appropriately, see Solomonoff's papers on the subject).

Comment: Thanks so much! Quick follow up question, does it matter what input machine M is fed with, i.e. does it have to be random input? Could it be data that we would normally classify as random, but in reality  just don't understand the underlying mechanism to, e.g. complex dynamical/chaotic systems?

Comment: Remember that $P_M(x)$ indicates the probability of output $x$ when $M$ is fed with an *ensemble* of inputs, not a single "random input" (however that is defined). I'm not sure how a chaotic system would be used to generate such an ensemble... do you have something in mind?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about what if we feed the Machine $M$ an ensemble of inputs from human generated data, like the stock market (which is not know with certainty if stochastic or not)? Would Algorithmic Probability work then as well?

Comment: I guess it depends on the distribution of the data... if its not random, then there are no guarantees regarding how the resulting output probabilities would behave.  Also keep in mind that if the input programs "look random" but have low Kolmogorov complexity, then you will only generate low Kolmogorov complexity outputs.